# bash script to launch freerdp with php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I will launch a bash scrip for php.
the echo of my bash displays the correct code syntax but does not launch ...

```
#!bin/bash  
var1=$1
var2=$2
config=$("xfreerdp /v:server.domain.tld /u:$1 /p:$2 /load-balance-info:\"tsv://ms terminal services plugin.1.programmes_remot\")
eval "$config"
```

I turn your senses after my php code

system("/var/www/test/./script.sh $var1 $var2");

I just tested the method 2 no error but its not launch xfreerdp this is what I put

```
$cmd='xfreerdp /v:server.domain.tld /u:'.$var1.' /p:'.$var2.' /f /cert-igore -menu-anims /network:lan  load-balance-info:"tsv://MS Terminal Services Plugin1.Programmes_Remot"';
exec('export display=guilinuxbox:0.0 $cmd');
```

but this does not launch

Answer (score 1):

A slash is missing in the she-bang: `#!/bin/bash`

Anyway, your script seems rather complicated. You could just write:

```
#!/bin/bash  
xfreerdp /v:server.domain.tld /u:$1 /p:$2 /load-balance-info:\"tsv://ms terminal services plugin.1.programmes_remot\"
```

or call `xfreedb` directly in your PHP script:

```
$var1 = escapeshellarg($var1);
$var2 = escapeshellarg($var2);
system("xfreerdp /v:server.domain.tld /u:$var1 /p:$var2 /load-balance-info:\"tsv://ms terminal services plugin.1.programmes_remot\"");
```

Note, that you should always [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) the variables that you put in a shell command for security reasons.

**Edit:**
Ah okay, it’s a GUI/X11 application. Are you running the PHP script on a Web server? Add `2>&1` to the command line string like this `system("...   2>&1")` to see any error messages in the HTML output.

I guess, you also need to explicitly [grant access to the screen](http://zweije.home.xs4all.nl/xauth-6.html).

Comment: hi joe,it's just a typo slash is present

Comment: Maybe another typo? Missing quote before the `)` at `programmes_remot\")`

Comment: I just tested the method 2 no error but its not launch xfreerdp this is what I put